# Teams chat belong to conversation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm using the Microsoft Graph API for my application.
I read that Microsoft Teams chat is stored in the Outlook of the sender.
To retrieve all the Teams Chat I use this request https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages (I know that it also return me all the outlook but I use some filter to return me only Teams Chat).
Now my question is how to know which Chats belong to the same conversation, I did not find in the metadata some property to help me.

Comment: Could you please share the filters which you used to get Teams messages?

Comment: $filter=subject eq 'IM'. I discovered that messages from teams show IM in the subject field.

Comment: I am sorry if it wakes you up on this topic but I had to ask I don't get Team Chat message with that filter ? $filter=subject eq 'IM'. Any Other filters possible. I am only converations and outlook emails but not Teams Chat Messages

Comment: Few month ago, they removed the IM from the subject, so now there is no way to filter.

Answer (score 1):

The Graph API for reading Teams conversations is not yet available but should be by around the end of June.

The API you are trying to use will not work.

Answer (score -2):

The APIs to read messages from a Microsoft Teams channel are available in preview.  I've created a multi-platform .NET Core application that demonstrates its use.  You can use it to download all of the messages from a specific channel within a Team, or all the channels in a Team.

https://github.com/tamhinsf/QuickTeams

Here are the underlying APIs that it uses:

To read the messages in a given channel.  This will return a paginated list of messages, each with a unique ID.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/channel_list_messages

Given a unique message ID, this will enable you to get the replies to the message.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/channel_list_messagereplies